# Placeholder Text Validation - PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, validation, placeholder, form-processing

I have 3 sets of 4 input fields that I want the user to complete and submit to my site. Fields are optional.
I have an **$all** variable that I am storing the data inside.

However, **if any input fields aren't completed**, then **I'd like to remove the placeholder text from the $all variable**.

Currently my output (**var_dump**) for completing the first row is:

```
string '1|1|1|1

Height (cm)|Width (cm)|Length (cm)|Weight (kg)

Height (cm)|Width (cm)|Length (cm)|

' (length=133)
```

**However, I'd like it to be:**

```
string '1|1|1|1' (length=7)
```

Here is my current code on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/2Je75vN0

As you can see, **placeholder text is placed inside the field using javascript** and the title attribute.

Can a very nice and gifted person please point me in the right direction with this? Or should I perhaps be using Javascript to validate this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Have you considered using HTML `placeholder=` attribute for your inputs? Much cleaner and more efficient than handling it on the server side.

Comment: That's a good idea. Will this work in IE8, IE7?

Comment: No, but you can use a JavaScript/jQuery fallback for those.

Comment: I've just found this after a Quick Google and think this could be the solution to my problems: http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/placeholder-support/ :-)

Comment: Should I post it as an answer than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using HTML5's `placeholder=` attribute (with a JavaScript fallback for older browser).

It's inefficient and it doesn't make sense to handle placeholders on the server side.

Comment: Brilliant advice, Truth. Good username ;-)